# how to put dynamic size of array of threads

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, c++11

As you can see, I want to create few threads.Now number of threads depends on the command line argument I get from console, so basically no of threads to be created has to be dynamic but creating array of objects of thread class in C++11 requires a const size to be given and that is where my problem arises as it is only accepting **"num_threads"** when it is initialized without using a variable(i.,e using a literal ).
***Like:               `static const int num_threads=10;`***
***But not in case of: `static const int num_threads=stoi(argv[1]);`***

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(argc!=2)
  {
     cout << "\n Invalid arguments \n";
     return 0;
  }

  static  const int num_threads = 10;// stoi(argv[1]);//
  thread t[num_threads];


 //Launch a group of threads
 for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) 
 {
    t[i] = std::thread(call_from_main_to_connect_info_disconnect, i);
 }

 std::cout << "Launched from the main\n";

//Join the threads with the main thread
 for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) 
 {
    t[i].join();
 }

 getchar();
 return err;

}
```

Any suggestions in order to have ***no of threads dynamic through command line*** input?

Comment: Use dynamic array, or since you re on c++ use `std::vector`

Comment: In C++ when you think "dynamic array" you should next be thinking [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
std::thread *t = new std::thread[num_threads];
```

or using `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::thread> t(num_threads);
```

Comment: genius stuff DimChtz.. worked for me. And idiotic for me as i should have thought of this concept.Using new operator u will allocate on heap and pass the address to a pointer (of type of class thread). Am I correct? Please tell if no.